# how to integrate sensio/generator-bundle in custom application - not symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, customization, symfony-console

I wrote a custom PHP application that is using Doctrine.
So `Doctrine` and the `symfony/console` component, as it's dependency are already installed.
Now Since `symfony/console` is already installed - I thought why not go all the way and install the `sensio/generator-bundle` component which gives me these wonderful code generation possibilities and ran
`composer require sensio/generator-bundle`

My composer.json

```
 "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "*",
    "symfony/finder": "^3.1",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.1"
}
```

After reading how to enable the sensio bundle on [symfony.com](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html)
I found out that - as with all bundles - , they have to be enabled in the `AppKernel.php` which ships with the symfony standard edition.

But  ! of course my **custom application** does not have a `AppKernel.php` I try o figure out how to integrate this extra bundle into my own code / workflow.

**Does anybody have experiences with this ?

And what are the important parts of the bundle that need to be registered / instantiated to work with them ?

Or is this simply to much work or not possible ?**

Any help appreciated  -- please --Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could manually register the commands but I'm guessing you don;t know how to do that.  The sensio bundles are written specifically for the Symfony framework.  What sort of wonderful code generation stuff were you thinking of?

Comment: Well for example the `generate:doctrine:crud` which creates a complete crud controller for a given entity that was created with `generate:doctrine:entity` and so on .... but it seems that theres no wy to do that unless installing the complete framework.

Comment: I will try to maybe adopt one or the other command to the doctrine console directly ....if that works

Comment: Because generating a crud makes little sense outside of a framework.  For example, Symfony crud controllers and views and not going to work under say Laravel or ZF.  But by all means experiment.

Comment: It is a framework .... so crud makes sense ...all the way. Like I said  ... doctrine custom commands are the way to go.